# Google Web Toolkit starter application not working

Tags: java, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to set Google Web Toolkit up on my system in order to tinker with creating web applications. I have been following the guide at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html to get some experience with the system. I have had some problems though. When I run the program in development mode (in Chromium) the page takes close to 10 seconds to load, and the send button does not do anything.

The output of the console is

```
Initializing AppEngine server
Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Successfully processed D:\Chris\Documents\My Dropbox\workspace\StockWatcher\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Successfully processed D:\Chris\Documents\My Dropbox\workspace\StockWatcher\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
[WARN] No file found for: /favicon.ico
```

And the output of the "Development Mode" is

```
[WARN] [stockwatcher] JSNI method '@com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.WindowImpl::initWindowCloseHandler()' returned a value of type JavaScript object(9) but was declared void; it should not have returned a value at all

[WARN] [stockwatcher] JSNI method '@com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DOMImplStandard::initEventSystem()' returned a value of type JavaScript object(193) but was declared void; it should not have returned a value at all
```

Any ideas about what is causing these problems and how to fix them? I know that I can add a file "favicon.ico" to war to take care of the one warning, but I havn't had any luck with the others.

I am using Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) and I installed the GWT plugin and SDK's as per google's guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use another browser, I think you are using Chrome 10.0.612.1 dev.
IMHO it could be caused by the WebKit update.

I have the same problem too, I just filled a bug: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5778

Comment: That was it! Since Chromium worked on my linux install I never thought that it would be the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing.. Have you checked the version compliance between GWT SDK installed onto Eclipse, and the libraries you are using in your GWT project classpath?

Comment: To my knowledge the only libraries on the classpath are the default ones. I'm doing this experimenting in a separate workspace from my other projects and I have not imported any other libraries yet. 

Edit: I checked, and the libraries in the project are App Engine SDK 1.4.0, 
GWT SDK 2.1.0, and
JRE System Library [jre6]

Comment: I must apologize, originally I asked this question since on my project we have in addition Maven environment, and in result GWT SDK appears in two 'places' - project build path, and as maven dependency. But since you are going through tutorial you obviously don't have such magic.. Btw, what is the version of Google Plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: No problem, I appreciate the help. There are many Google plugins installed. The Google Core Plugin is 1.4.0v201010280047 and the Google Web Toolkit is 2.1.0v201010280047. I think those are the ones you are interested in.

Comment: The last thing I could suggest you - as a last resort (since I obviously don't know what's the problem) - trying to update Google Plugin for Eclipse/GWT SDK from Eclipse's 'Installed Software', or even uninstalling & installing again from the appropriate Eclipse version update site (which probably is already correctly done..)

Comment: Update: It works fine on my laptop. Eclipse is configured the same on it as it is on my desktop, except that the laptop runs Ubuntu 10.10 while my desktop runs Windows 7 x64. I tried reinstalling the plugins without success. Im thinking it might be time to simply reinstall eclipse.. perhaps upgrade to 3.6 instead of 3.5. Would you agree?

Comment: Update 2: installed eclipse 3.6, redownloaded and installed GWT, still the same problems.

Comment: the issue is gwt incompatibility with chrome dev, not eclipse.